# logback doesn't find maven's property project.build.directory

Tags: spring, maven, properties, spring-boot, logback

I have a small project with Spring Boot and maven, and now I'm trying to configure logback to write to a file. I want it to write to a file given by `${project.build.directory}/${log.folder}/logfile.log`, so a subfolder of the build directory, being `${log.folder}` a property that I specify in an `application.properties` file, places under my `/resources` folder.

This is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.glassfish.jersey" level="DEBUG"/>

    <property resource="application.properties"/>

    <appender name="DUMMY_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${project.build.directory}/${log.folder}/logfile.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz"}, [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/spring.log.%d</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="xxxxxx" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="DUMMY_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="DUMMY_APPENDER"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

It writes the logs, but my problem is that when I run the application, it creates a folder project.build.directory_IS_UNDEFINED, then places my log.folder under it. It says [in the documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html), that

> As its build tool, logback relies on Maven, a widely-used open-source
>   build tool.

And when, in the logback.xml, I start typing ${pro... then my IDE displays a set of available [maven implicit properties](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html).

So it should work, but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work due to what @luboskmac said.

Here is how to make it work. I have reproduced the problem and pushed up a solution here : https://github.com/ajorpheus/logback-maven/releases

Here is a summary of the fix : https://github.com/ajorpheus/logback-maven/commit/f245e5a6f4c13f9ba8e161c5452d296b653977d0

1. Define a property in the pom to hold the location of your logfile:

   [image]
2. Use the property in the `logback.xml` appender:

[image]

3. Enable maven resource filtering so that any maven properties defined in the the resources being scanned are replaced with their corresponding values

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`${project.build.directory}` is Maven's property, which is available only during the maven build. On the other hand, Logback is being used on runtime of the application. So obviously `${project.build.directory}` is not defined on runtime.

You need to pick location which will be tailored to runtime environment and your deployment topology.

Answer (score -1):

You can use deployment container properties.

Like for tomcat

```
${catalina.base}/logs
```