# Logback NOT writing in log.txt

Tags: java, logback

**Problem Statement:** Logback is printing in console properly but not in log.txt file. There are many solutions given in other pages but apparently none worked. Could someone help me in this regard?

**Java:-**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Log {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Example App");
        logger.info("'sup? I'm your info logger");
        logger.debug("hey HEY hey! I'm your debug logger");
    }
}
```

**Config:-** logback-fileAppender.xml

```xml
<configuration>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${project.basedir}/Log.txt</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- set immediateFlush to false for much higher logging throughput -->
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

**Expected:-** The logs should be printed in log.txt
**Actual:-** The logs is not printed in log.txt

**Note:** I am using my customized directory structure in maven not the default provided by maven "src/main/resources".

Comment: Does it work if you name the file `logback.xml` and put it in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: As I said, I am not following src/ main/resources structure in my project. I did try with logback.xml but no luck.

Comment: @Learner Is your program reading your logback configuration? You can verify it with `debug="true"`.

Comment: I understand you're not following the default structure. Since you posted your configuration file but did not show how you configured Logback to use a non-default directory and non-default file name I'm guessing you think the problem is in the file.  The easiest troubleshooting step is to see if the configuration file works when it is in the default location with the default name. If it does then you will know that your file is correct.

Comment: @Learner You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313502/logback-doesnt-find-mavens-property-project-build-directory

Comment: @Learner Please [edit] your question to include the POM file you are using. Then write the (maven) commands you use to build and run your application.

Comment: Test it with `java -cp .;The_SNAPSHOT.jar foo.bar.App` and put logback.xml in the current directory. Change the semicolon to colon if not on WIndows

Comment: Try `-Dlogback.configurationFile=...` to give logback the absolute path to the config file.

Comment: Are you sure that `project.basedir` is available as a system property or environment variable? That's usually a maven property.